# Angular append interpolation to conditional

Tags: angular

I'm trying to append the value I get form "artist.artistName" to the end of the URL  https://via.placeholder.com/286x286?text=

So if my artistName = 'Muse', my URL should read https://via.placeholder.com/286x286?text=Muse

But I can't seem to get the append and interpolation right.

```
<div *ngFor="let artist of searchArray ">
    <img [src]="artist.images.length > 0 ? artist.images[0].url : 'https://via.placeholder.com/286x286?text='+artist.artistName"  alt="Card image cap">
</div>
```

When I do this ^ the value of artist.artistName is undefined. Yet if i do

`<p>{{artist.artistName}}</p>`

displays Muse.

What's the correct way to append the value to a conditional?

Answer (score 0):

This one should work.
artist.images[0].url : 'https://via.placeholder.com/286x286?text={{artist.artistName"}}'
if you look at the tutorial in angular.io. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5
You will find the below example:
 the routerLink text is appended with hero.id like this {{hero.id}}.

```
<a *ngFor="let hero of heroes" class="col-1-4" 
routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
<div class="module hero">
<h4>{{hero.name}}</h4>
</div>
</a>
```